# Loading incorrect JSON into Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have had a LOT of trouble loading data given to me into a `CSV` so it can be appended into a database.

Below is just a sample part of the file out of thousands.

```
{"op":"mcm","clk":"700198762","pt":1431081247897,"mc":[{"id":"1.118690816","marketDefinition": 
{"bspMarket":false,"turnInPlayEnabled":false,"persistenceEnabled":true,"marketBaseRate":5.0,"eventId":"13864349","eventTypeId":"2378961","numberOfWinners":1,"bettingType":"ODDS","marketTime":"2015-05-08T08:00:00.000Z","suspendTime":"2015-05-08T08:00:00.000Z","bspReconciled":false,"complete":true,"inPlay":false,"crossMatching":false,"runnersVoidable":false,"numberOfActiveRunners":5,"betDelay":0,"status":"SUSPENDED","runners":[{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":1,"id":9469881,"name":"May 8th"},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":2,"id":9469904,"name":"May 9th - 11th"},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":3,"id":9469905,"name":"May 12th - 14th"},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":4,"id":9469906,"name":"May 15th - 17th"},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":5,"id":9469907,"name":"May 18th or Later"}],"regulators":["MR_INT"],"countryCode":"GB","discountAllowed":false,"timezone":"Europe/London","openDate":"2015-06-30T23:00:00.000Z","version":979981567,"name":"Nigel Farage","eventName":"Leader Exit Dates"},"rc":[],"con":true,"img":false}]}
{"op":"mcm","clk":"700198958","pt":1431081251954,"mc":[{"id":"1.118690816","marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":false,"turnInPlayEnabled":false,"persistenceEnabled":true,"marketBaseRate":5.0,"eventId":"13864349","eventTypeId":"2378961","numberOfWinners":1,"bettingType":"ODDS","marketTime":"2015-05-08T08:00:00.000Z","suspendTime":"2015-05-08T08:00:00.000Z","bspReconciled":false,"complete":true,"inPlay":false,"crossMatching":false,"runnersVoidable":false,"numberOfActiveRunners":0,"betDelay":0,"status":"CLOSED","settledTime":"2015-05-08T10:34:11.000Z","runners":[{"status":"REMOVED","sortPriority":1,"id":9469881,"name":"May 8th"},{"status":"REMOVED","sortPriority":2,"id":9469904,"name":"May 9th - 11th"},{"status":"REMOVED","sortPriority":3,"id":9469905,"name":"May 12th - 14th"},{"status":"REMOVED","sortPriority":4,"id":9469906,"name":"May 15th - 17th"},{"status":"REMOVED","sortPriority":5,"id":9469907,"name":"May 18th or Later"}],"regulators":["MR_INT"],"countryCode":"GB","discountAllowed":false,"timezone":"Europe/London","openDate":"2015-06-30T23:00:00.000Z","version":979981755,"name":"Nigel Farage","eventName":"Leader Exit Dates"},"rc":[],"con":true,"img":false}]}
```

I know what the problem is, it is meant to be a list of objects yet there are no brackets or commas signifying this. There are two schools of thought for a solution, one is fixing the data or two is working with the data and get it into a pandas dataframe. I would much prefer option 2 because there is a sea of json files and more are being downloaded by the day and fixing them might be inefficient if I could just load it into a pandas dataframe no problem. But if that is the only solution I will happily take it. I have experimented with dirtyjson (python library) so I can use pd.normalise and getting this error.

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

When I try load it normally with the json library I get this.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 3617)
```

If you need more information I will supply it as soon as I see the post.

My code is this.

```
def JSONtoCSV(testdir):
    json_data = open(testdir)
    json_data = json_data.read()

    #data = dirtyjson.loads(json_data)
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    print(data)

    jsonDF = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['mc'], meta=['op', 'clk', 'pt'], errors='ignore')
    json_data.close()
    return jsonDF
```

Comment: [This](https://sportsbettingquant.com/blog/how-to-use-betfair-historical-data/) may be helpful

Comment: Thats awesome thank you @RJAdriaansen. Just checking it now